# How to read large data files in R allocating memory dynamically?

Tags: r, import, sas

Is there a way to read large data files in R allocating memory dynamically in the same way as SAS does?

I'm referring to the import of a SAS data set. While SAS has no problem reading large files because it allocates memory dynamically, R is unusable from a certain size on because it allocates in RAM the whole file size.

I gave a look at the ff package as it keeps a pointer to file on disk but it doesn't have a read method for sas datasets.

So, **is there a way to read a file allocating memory dynamically, in particular while importing a SAS data set?**

Comment: I do not believe you will find a package that allocates memory dynamically in the same was as SAS. Without specifics I cannot be much help--but it seems your best option would be to create some workflow selecting columns from your dataset using `haven::read_sas()`

Comment: Closest thing in R is the [vroom package](https://github.com/r-lib/vroom) I believe. You'll have to convert the SAS file to csv or something first though, which you can of course do in SAS if it's too much memory for R.

Comment: Good call @IceCreamToucan, I was thinking about a package that works specifically with SAS datasets and should have clarified.